# Access the returned latlng values from the fusiontable query

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm wondering if it's possible to access the latlng values that are returned from the query below. The query itself works fine, but for what I'm building I would need to know the center location of a country.

I know how to find the center latlng based on a collection of latlng values, but I just can't find a way how to access the returned latlng values from the fusion table query.

Not sure if that is even possible? I tried to do console.log(layer) and see if I could find an array or so with the returned latlng values, but unless I'm missing something it's not there.

If what I want is possible, how would I access the those values? Or any other suggestion on how to access the latng values for the polygons?

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
  select: 'geometry',
  from: '17mMrmy5DaEPNlPabZeKrTmY3e8cP7-qCFrrFyxk',
  where: "iso_a3 IN ('AFG', 'NZL')"
},
styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#ff22ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.3
  }
}]
});

layer.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the information from the FusionTableLayer except on a click event.

Click on the polygons in [this map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoD.html?lat=2.704860&lng=110.360840&zoom=2&type=m&tableid=17mMrmy5DaEPNlPabZeKrTmY3e8cP7-qCFrrFyxk&tablequery=geometry&tablewhere=iso_a3%20IN%20%28%27AFG%27%2C%20%27NZL%27%29) you will see the coordinates in the infowindow.

You can query the FusionTable using GViz or the FusionTables API v1.0 to get the information required.

[Here is an example that parses the coordinates using the FusionTables API v1.0 and renders them on a map as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 polygons](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linktoC.html?lat=-5.248074&lng=92.638405&zoom=2&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20geometry,%20name%20FROM&tableid=17mMrmy5DaEPNlPabZeKrTmY3e8cP7-qCFrrFyxk&where=iso_a3%20IN%20%28%27AFG%27,%20%27NZL%27%29)